# Asp.net core 5.0 Response cache ignoring duration directive on controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, caching

trying my hand at Response caching in asp.net core 5.  So I have set things up and am seeing it appear to work, but it is using the global directive and ignoring the attributes I applied to the individual controller.

My Controller:

```
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 300)]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<PublicMenu> GetPublicMenu(string UserRole)
```

My startup.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XYZPublic.Models;
using XYZPublic.Models.EF;
using XYZPublic.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace XYZPublic
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Env = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IWebHostEnvironment Env { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        var builder = services.AddRazorPages();

        if (Env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        }


        services.AddDbContext<XYZContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("XYZContext")));

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
        services.AddTransient<PublicMenuService, PublicMenuService>();
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );
        
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);


        //Password Strength Setting  
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings  
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            
            // Lockout settings  
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings  
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });

        //Seting the Account Login page  
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings  
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30); // 30 day login
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login"; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login  
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout"; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout  
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied  
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Home/Index", "");
        });

        services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
        services.AddResponseCaching();
        

        //var environment = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();

        // below is potential remedy to 30 minute logouts - may not be necessary
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName($"my-app-{Env.EnvironmentName}")
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo($@"{Env.ContentRootPath}\keys"));


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        // next 2 testing TODO 
        app.UseResponseCaching();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
                new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
                {
                    Public = true,
                    MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                };
            context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Vary] =
                new string[] { "Accept-Encoding" };

            await next();
        });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "catalog",
                pattern: "{controller}/{type?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Index" });

            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

}

So what I am expecting is that a get to GetPublicMenu caches responses for 300sec, but it is instead deferring to the 10 second cache of the startup.cs code.  These are the beginning of several services that need specific response caching times in my app.  I have tried several different response directives on the controller, like this one with no change. [ResponseCache(NoStore = false, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client, Duration = 60)]

I am testing as with SQLprofiler noting that my DB is hit ever 10 seconds.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share your `startup.cs` file contents? Thank you

Comment: Thank you, added.  Its not been fully gone through yet so it’s a bit of a junkyard.

Comment: Does your `GetPublicMenu` return a HTTP 200 OK?

Comment: Also, is this perhaps an authorised endpoint as I can see a `UserRole` parameter?